# Redirect After Authentication Not Working. No Path in History

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, web-deployment, auth0

Redirect after login with Auth0 is not working in my React app. I followed the code from the [official tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-react-user-authentication/).

The `window.location.pathname` pushes just "/" to history and thus redirects me my homepage upon refreshing the page.

The `appState` prop seems to always be undefined in my code. Auth0 doesn’t seem to be assigning a value to it. Am I missing something?

Anyone have this issue in React or Auth0 before?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const Auth0ProviderWithHistory = ({ children }) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const domain = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
    const clientId = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
    const audience = process.env.REACT_APP_AUDIENCE;

  const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
    history.push(appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
  };

  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
      audience={audience}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};

export default Auth0ProviderWithHistory;
```

My routing structure

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import Auth0ProviderWithHistory from './Auth0ProviderWithHistory';

// Components
import Router from  './Router';
import { Navbar, Footer } from './components/';


const NavbarWithRouter = withRouter(Navbar);


export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Auth0ProviderWithHistory>
          <NavbarWithRouter />
          <Router />
          <Footer />
        </Auth0ProviderWithHistory>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `BrowserRouter` and `Router` both?   also they use `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";`

Comment: Router is a component with all my routes in between <Switch> tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had same kind of problem. After some dependency problem and updating npm packages this weird message appeared:

[image]

I overcame the problem by the help of a auth0community message..https://community.auth0.com/t/redirecting-after-login/39821...offering that:

```js
const onRedirectCallback = appState => {
  history.push(
    appState && appState.targetUrl
      ? appState.targetUrl
      : window.location.href = "https://www.exampleroute.com/pointofredirect"
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So, this is how I got it working.

1. redirectUri: provide the link to which the user should be redirected after successful authentication.
2. Allowed Callback URLs: In your app settings in Auth0, YOU MUST PROVIDE all routes that you have on your website. (These are the routes where the Auth0 can redirect a user after authentication)
3. Process: React app reads the current href path -> Auth0Provider passes below credentials to Auth0 server for authentication -> After Authentication, Auth0 checks if redirectUri matches one of the callback URLs and redirects to that URL if a match is found else it will throw an error saying callback URLs are not setup correctly

**Notes:**

1. Providing "window.location.orgin" to redirectUri will always tell Auth0 to redirect to the root of the URL (ex: [www.example.com/](http://www.example.com/))
2. onRedirectCallback: This is a callback function, called after the user is redirected from auth0. So there is no meaning in using it for redirection as the user was already redirected. These 2 points are the reason why appState is undefined and it always redirects to "/"

```html
<Auth0Provider
  domain={domain}
  clientId={clientId}
  audience={audience}
  redirectUri={window.location.href}
>
```

**EDIT:**
A Better Solution:

Keep redirectUri={window.location.origin}.

This saves us from adding all the routes into auth0. So we should only add the origin uri in the callback URL in auth0 portal.

Then how to redirect to the old page?

1. Before redirect happens store the current href into a cookie
2. Auth0 will authorize the user and redirect to the origin URL (ex: localhost:3002/)
3. At the root page (app.js) in a useEffect() check if the cookie exists.
   Delete the cookie and redirect user to the uri that was stored in the
   Cookie.
4. **NOTE:** I had to use a ternary operator that redirects the user to redirectUri cookie if it exists else to the default homepage of the user with the help of <Navigate /> from react-router-dom because the useNavigate() kept refreshing the page.

Comment: "Before redirect happens store the current href into a cookie" — how is that done?